# Relaxing binary variable but having the same solution

Tags: integer-programming

I have this MIP optimization problem, with couple of binary variables; however when I relax one of the binary variables the optimal solution of the objective does not change. But the solving time increase drastically. How could this happen? 
I noticed that this only happens for just when only I relax that specific variable, not for the rest. Does it like this that when you relax a variable the solution space does not change? is the some MIP optimization logic or property behind this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would post this on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can happen. The solver follows a different path. With MIPs a "better" formulation can be slower on some instances even if faster on average.